# How do i round in mysql table

Tags: mysql, rounding

How do i round time to nearest 15 minute in mysql column working_hours `HH:MM:SS`
I have tryed the following:

```
UPDATE student SET `working_hours` =  
REPLACE(working_hours,SUBSTRING_INDEX(working_hours, ' ', -1),
SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(working_hours) DIV 60) * 60))
```

This is only rounding down to nearest quarter

Thanks

Comment: So the output should have minutes in `00`, `15`, `30` and `45` and seconds in `00`?

Comment: Why update and replace? UPDATE student SET `working_hours` = SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(working_hours) DIV 60) * 60)) not work?

Comment: Sorry pasted the wrong code :P - UPDATE student SET `working_hours` =  REPLACE(working_hours,SUBSTRING_INDEX(working_hours, ' ', -1),SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(working_hours) DIV 900) * 900))

Comment: this might not be smart enough ... but have a try UPDATE student SET `working_hours` =  
if( MINUTE(time(working_hours))<= 15, concat(HOUR(working_hours) ,':00'), 
if( MINUTE(time(working_hours)) between 16 and 29,concat(HOUR(working_hours) ,':15'),
if( MINUTE(time(working_hours)) between 31 and 45,concat(HOUR(working_hours) ,':30'), concat(HOUR(working_hours),':45'))))